# Marshal slice with jsonapi

Tags: go

I have a slice of structs and I want to marshal it using https://github.com/google/jsonapi.

With a single struct, everything works fine. I simply pass a pointer as a second argument.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/google/jsonapi"
)

type Spider struct {
    ID       int `jsonapi:"primary,spiders"`
    EyeCount int `jsonapi:"attr,eye_count"`
}

func main() {
    jsonapi.MarshalPayload(os.Stdout, &Spider{ID: 2, EyeCount: 12})
    // {"data":{"type":"spiders","id":"2","attributes":{"eye_count":12}}}
}
```

---

However, when I'm trying to do the same with a slice, things are quite different.

First of all, I'm converting my slice to a slice of pointers to those structs (don't know what else to do here, passing pointer to the slice didn't work).

```
spiders := []Spider{Spider{ID: 1, EyeCount: 8}, Spider{ID: 2, EyeCount: 12}}

var spiderPointers []*Spider
for _, x := range spiders {
    spiderPointers = append(spiderPointers, &x)
}
jsonapi.MarshalPayload(os.Stdout, spiderPointers)
```

It works. Sort of. Here is the issue:

```
{"data":[
  {"type":"spiders","id":"2","attributes":{"eye_count":12}},
  {"type":"spiders","id":"2","attributes":{"eye_count":12}}]}
```

The last element is repeated and it replaces other elements.

In the end, I came up with a somewhat working solution:

```
spiders := []Spider{Spider{ID: 1, EyeCount: 8}, Spider{ID: 2, EyeCount: 12}}
var spiderPointers []interface{}
for _, x := range spiders {
    var spider Spider
    spider = x
    spiderPointers = append(spiderPointers, &spider)
}

jsonapi.MarshalPayload(os.Stdout, spiderPointers)
// {"data":[{"type":"spiders","id":"1","attributes":{"eye_count":8}},
//          {"type":"spiders","id":"2","attributes":{"eye_count":12}}]}
```

But I'm sure there must be a better way, hence this question.

Comment: Further confirmation your working example is appropriate 
https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Answer (score 1):

Curious would you be able to use something like this??

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/google/jsonapi"
)

type Spider struct {
    ID       int `jsonapi:"primary,spiders"`
    EyeCount int `jsonapi:"attr,eye_count"`
}

func main() {
    // spiders is a slice of interfaces.. they can be unmarshalled back to spiders later if the need arises
    // you don't need a loop to create pointers either... so better in memory usage and a bit cleaner to read.. you can in theory load the []interface{} with a for loop as well since you mentioned getting this data from a db
    var spiders []interface{}
    spiders = append(spiders, &Spider{ID: 1, EyeCount: 8}, &Spider{ID: 2, EyeCount: 12})
    fmt.Println("jsonapi, MarshalPayload")
    jsonapi.MarshalPayload(os.Stdout, spiders)

    // test against marshall indent for sanity checking
    b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(spiders, "", " ")
    fmt.Println("marshall indent")
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

Comment: >"spiders is a slice of interfaces.."


Sorry, I think I should have phrased it better. The original slice that I get from the db is `spiders := []Spider{Spider{ID: 1, EyeCount: 8}, Spider{ID: 2, EyeCount: 12}}`. It's not a slice of interfaces but a slice of Spiders. That's why I convert it to a slice of interfaces using a for loop in the question.

Comment: Since jsonapi requires a slice of interfaces.. Then perhaps you are already doing the best thing. The only cleaner option in my mind is not to use. jsonapi and to create your own costume marshaller. Given jsonapi also relies heavily on interfaces and reflection is already going to be super slow by comparison.

Comment: I think you're right, I just looked at https://github.com/manyminds/api2go and it seems to be better suited for this case (it doesn't require performing such conversion https://github.com/manyminds/api2go#manual-marshalling--unmarshalling)

Comment: I just checked it out I also think you'll have a better time with api2go

Answer (score 0):

Why not that way [either3]?

```
var spiders interface{}
db.Model(spiders).Select()
jsonapi.MarshalPayload(os.Stdout, spiders)
```

Comment: Ah, that's because I'm getting those records from a database and the database library returns the records in such form.

Comment: Why not that way either?

Comment: I tried it, but in this case MarshalPayload simply doesn't write anything to Stdout. No errors though.

Comment: What (which type) does the database return?

Comment: I use go-pg. So first I define a slice like so `var spiders []Spider` then invoke the library function that writes to it like so `db.Model(&spiders).Select()`.

Comment: in other words, `[]Spider` is the type I'm trying to work with.

Comment: Why not that [either2]?

Comment: It compiles but it makes `db.Model` return the `pg: Model(nil)` error.

Comment: I guess because https://godoc.org/github.com/go-pg/pg#Model (or some of the functions that it calls internally) doesn't expect a pointer.

Comment: Do you really need that typing? Maybe just use interface{} and cast only if you need to change or read particular fields. [either3]

Comment: The way I understand it, the type allows the library to deduce the table name and fields when talking to the database. So if I pass interface{} to db.Model, it doesn't know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a pointer issue, not a jsonapi issue.

When you loop over a value, the loop variable is created once and the value is reassigned over and over again. A pointer to a loop variable will always point to the same address and you just keep updating the value. This leaves you with a slice repeating the same pointer all of which point to the last value placed there.

The solution is to create a scoped closure that captures the value in a new variable and then use that variable's pointer. Try the following:

```go
spiders := []Spider{Spider{ID: 1, EyeCount: 8}, Spider{ID: 2, EyeCount: 12}}

var spiderPointers []*Spider
for _, x := range spiders {
    x := x // capture loop variable
    spiderPointers = append(spiderPointers, &x)
}
jsonapi.MarshalPayload(os.Stdout, spiderPointers)
```